# Using PHP in a JavaScript Function in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I declared a variable empty in external JavaScript file which I am sourcing in my main HTML page and because I want to load that variable from PHP I am doing this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var APIKey = <?php echo $API; ?></script>
```

script.js is the one having empty global variable like this:

```
var APIKey = "";
```

I have already declared $API in PHP and I know it's working because I tried echoing it as text and it works but for some reason it doesn't in script. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Is './assets/js/script.js' using the variable before it is defined in your second code statement?  Have you tried putting the php echo script above script.js to load it first?

Comment: How are you using this js files on your php files? Show us that as well.

Comment: In order to set a JS variable, that has already been established, from PHP you will have to use AJAX to get the PHP value and use the return to set the JS variable.

Comment: Patrick, I am using the variable before it was defined again and I have tried putting it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it took a bit time to figure out but the mistake was pretty simple.

All I had to do was **REMOVE** this from script.js

```
var APIKey = "";
```

The problem was that I was defining it 2 times and I don't think that's supported for some reason but that worked for me so if anyone else has the same issue, it'll work for you as well. Have a good day and keep on coding.